# Can someone tell me why my program works in Python 2.7 and not 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these two functions:

```
def MatchRNA(RNA, start1, end1, start2, end2):
    Subsequence1 = RNA[start1:end1+1]
    if start1 > end1:
        Subsequence1 = RNA[start1:end1-1:-1]
    Subsequence2 = RNA[start2:end2+1]
    if start2 > end2:
        Subsequence2 = RNA[start2:end2-1:-1]
    return Subsequence1, Subsequence2


def main():
    RNA_1_list = ['A','U','G','U','G','G','G','U','C','C','A','C','G','A','C','U','C','G','U','C','G','U','C','U','A','C','U','A','G','A']
    RNA_2_list = ['C','U','G','A','C','G','A','C','U','A','U','A','A','G','G','G','U','C','A','A','G','C']
    RNA_Values = {'A': 1, 'U': 2, 'C': 3, 'G': 4}
    RNA1 = []
    RNA2 = []
    for i in RNA_1_list:
        if i in RNA_Values:
            RNA1.append(RNA_Values[i])
    for i in RNA_2_list:
        if i in RNA_Values:
            RNA2.append(RNA_Values[i])
    RNA = list(input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? "))       
    Start1, End1, Start2, End2 = eval(input("What are the start and end values (Start1, End1, Start2, End2) for the subsequences of the strand? "))
    Sub1, Sub2 = MatchRNA(RNA, Start1, End1, Start2, End2)
    print(Sub1)
    print(Sub2)
```

So when I run the main function, and give as input (for example): RNA1, and then 3, 14, 17, 28, it should print two lists, `[2,4,4,4,2,3,3,1,3,4,1,3]` and `[4,2,3,4,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,4]`. I was inadvertently using Python 2.7 when I was testing this code, and it worked fine (without that eval in there), but when I run it in 3.3 (and put the eval back in) it prints two lists, ['1'] and []. Does anyone know why it doesn't work in 3.3 or how I can get it to work in 3.3? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` returns a string in Python3 while in Python2 it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input)`.

For `RNA1` as input:

**Python3:**

```
>>> RNA1 = []
>>> list(input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? "))
Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? RNA1
['R', 'N', 'A', '1']
```

**Python2:**

```
>>> list(eval(input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? ")))
Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? RNA1
[]
```

Comment: But doesn't doing `eval(input())` change it from a string to integers?

Comment: @user2934394 `eval` expects a string not list, python2's `input()` already converts your string to `list`.

Comment: @user2934394 Simply use `input` in py3.x and `raw_input` in py2.x. There's also a py2to3 tool that can convert the program for you.

Comment: I'm just confused because the way I have it written up above, with `eval(input())`, the values for Start1, End1, Start2, and End2 are being converted to integers (I checked to make sure), but for some reason when it plugs these values into the MatchRNA() function, it doesn't work, even though it did in Python2

Comment: @kindrex735, see my answer:  Start1 etc are only *part* of the problem, and they're not the *main* part of the problem ;-)

Comment: @kindrex735 Have you tried: `eval(input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? "))`?

Answer (score 0):

Close, but the main source of your problem is here:

```
 RNA = list(input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? "))
```

The `list()` call there is useless in any case.

In Python2, when you enter `RNA1`, `input()` evaluates that symbol and returns the list bound to `RNA1`.

In Python3, `input()` returns the *string* `"RNA1"`, which the pointless ;-) `list()` turns into

```
['R', 'N', 'A', '1']
```

One way to change the code to run under both versions:  first add this at the top:

```
try:
    raw_input
except:  # Python 3
    raw_input = input
```

Then change the input lines:

```
RNA = eval(raw_input("Which strand of RNA (RNA1 or RNA2) are you sequencing? "))
Start1, End1, Start2, End2 = eval(raw_input("What are the start and end values (Start1, End1, Start2, End2) for the subsequences of the strand? "))
```